# J48 Decision Tree only uses one attribute in dataset to classify output, why is this happening and how can I get it to use all the attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree

This may be a stupid question, so I apologise in advance. I'm currently using weka to classify performance  using a number of attributes. However after running the J48 model on a 70/30 split, and visualising the decision tree, there is only one attribute being used, as opposed to all of them. Where have I went wrong and how do I fix it?[this is what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxfJ.png)

Comment: One variable used in a tree does't mean there is something wrong. Especially if you have only four end end nodes. I suggest to allow smaller end nodes to increase the tree or run it in some other tool (R for example) to see if it produces different results.

Comment: As @Jan_Kislinger notes, profit might be by far the best predictor.  But to investigate this, drop profit from your data and rerun J48.  It's possible that the other attributes are miscoded in some way.